# Mysql, innodb - Can't create foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

Using the default engine (MyIsam), I'm able to create a foreign key with this syntax:

```
alter table `codes` add constraint foreign key(`associated_code_id`) references ask_codes(code_id)  on update cascade on delete cascade;
```

However, when i create the table using INNODB I'm no longer able to create the foreign key (mysql gives me ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'my_table.#sql-3311_16115' (errno: 150) ).

Is this a syntax issue?  Thanks for the help,

Comment: According to the docs: Cannot create table. If the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You problem is that both columns don't have the same type - they don't match exactly:

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition
>   that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must
>   have the right column names and types, and it must have indexes on the
>   referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied,  MySQL
>   returns error number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error
>   message.

Comment: Yep thanks.  Need index(col_name) on both contraints and exact match in temrs of type...

Answer (score 1):

I add to @phpGeek's great answer that also you need to have same LENGTH in numeric values, that means if table A has "id INT(11)" table B must have "A_id INT(11)" as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the ALTER statement for the MyISAM table it silently ignores the FK constraint, if I remember correctly. When you run it for InnoDB it tries to validate the constraint by applying it to the table. I think this error occurs when the FK constraint fails for an existing row - [InnoDB Error Codes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html)

You could try the following query to see what values are blocking the constraint creation -

```
SELECT *
FROM codes
LEFT JOIN ask_codes
    ON codes.associated_code_id = ask_codes.code_id
WHERE ask_codes.code_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - both tables are EMPTY so this query whilst valid returns nothing!

Comment: @rix - In that case it is probably because ask_codes is a MyISAM table or there is a datatype mismatch. It needs to be InnoDB and both fields must be of the same datatype.

Answer (score -6):

I believe this is simply a limitation of InnoDB. It does not support foreign keys. At least that's how I walked away from this issue last time it hit me.

Comment: Other way around. MyISAM does not support FK constraints.

Comment: Nope. InnoDB supports FK - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html